# D3, combine FishEye with brushing and updated scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fisheye

I am working on [a project](http://medvis.laureif80.eighty.axc.nl/) where I have to create a scatterplot with genes denoted by dots. Since there are a lot of genes (20k), they get clustered and are stacked often, even after brushing and zooming in on the brush.

[image: clustered points]

To allow the user to separate them a bit better, I want to implement D3's [FishEye plugin](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/), preferably the Cartesian. I [implemented the example](http://medvis.laureif80.eighty.axc.nl/javascript/fish_eye_control.js), but the points are flying outside the screen. My guess is that this happens because if you brush (and zoom in), the scales and axes are updated.

How can I make my FishEye adhere to the current domain of the axes in terms of the distortion range and how can I make the points translate correctly (and not fly outside the screen) ? I have already tried something with the min and maximum x-values, but that doesn't work either.